# How can we listen to an event dispatched in PopUpWindow inside the parent component?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, events, actionscript, event-handling

I have a warning Popwindow with 2 buttons 'Submit' and 'Cancel'.
On clicking submit I invoke a function and dispatch 'submit' Event with bubble true. I want to handle this inside my parent application. I have already registered the event with the parent container as well as the popup instance.

```
Inside Parent.mxml :


private function launchWarningPopUp():void {
        var win:Warning = PopUpManager.createPopUp(this, Warning, false ) as Warning; 
        win.addEventListener(SubmitQuizEvent.SUBMIT_QUIZ, submissionDone);
        this.addEventListener(SubmitQuizEvent.SUBMIT_QUIZ, submissionDone);
        PopUpManager.centerPopUp(win);
}

private function submissionDone():void{
   Alert.show('Inside SubmissionDoneTwo');
}
```

---

```
Inside Warning.mxml:

private function submitHanlder():void {
            dispatchEvent(new SubmitQuizEvent(SubmitQuizEvent.SUBMIT_QUIZ,true));
            PopUpManager.removePopUp(this);
}
```

---

The event should bubble to Parent.mxml.
Am I doing something wrong here or is it simply not possible ?

I am stuck here, any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to catch this event inside my function as the signature was missing. After I add this the code worked.

```
private function submissionDone(event:SubmitQuizEvent):void{

            Alert.show('Inside SubmissionDone with signature');
}
```

=================================================================================

I am facing another issue now.
The event is captured **only when I use ' win.addEventListener....'** and not with 'this.addEventListener ............'.This is surprizing to me.

If Parent.mxml is parent of 'win' then **the events triggered  inside 'win' should bubble and should be caught by the parent.** This is not happening.

Is 'win' not considered child of the Parent.mxml ? And is treated as external component ?

Please let me know your view on this ??

Answer (score 1):

You should add your event listener to the systemManager because popups are direct children of the system manager

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.  the popup is not a child of the component that creates it.  It is, as Florian said, a child of systemManager and events don't bubble as you might expect.